# Filter out documents before indexing in Elasticsearch based on certain condition

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, elasticsearch-5

I was wondering if I could filter our documents before indexing in Elasticsearch based on specific condition. For example, let's say I would like to drop a document from being index if `field1="something"`. Is this something I can address via using out of the box processors in Elasticsearch and use "ingest node" to cover it? Can I write a custom processor if it doesn't exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do this directly in Elasticsearch using pipelines (see [this issue](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/30173)).

However, Logstash has a [drop](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-drop.html) filter designed exactly for this and which may be useful in your case.